# Please explain this mysterious $.getJSON behaviour

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, firebug

```
var test = $.getJSON( 'data/mydata.json' );

console.log( test );
console.log( JSON.stringify(test) );
```

The first log statement outputs:
[image]

The second line outputs:

```
{"readyState":1}
```

What happened to my data? Do I really have to pass a function in order to grab responseJSON (note that I'im not working on production code)?

But foremost, is this possible. I wouldn't know how to do such a thing if I wanted.

Comment: Ajax stands for asynchroneus. Yes, the design pattern implied that  you have to give it a callback. There you just read some file so it's fast enough. But $.getJSON return a jQuery xhr-like object. Not your data.

Answer (score 3):

`test` here is `jQuery XHR` object, not your returned data. To get your returned data, try:

```
$.getJSON( 'data/mydata.json' ,function(data){
     console.log( data);
     console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
});
```

or a more recommended way:

```
$.getJSON( "data/mydata.json").done(function(data) { 
     console.log( data);
     console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
});
```

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
>   the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR,"
>   returned by $.getJSON() implements the Promise interface, giving it
>   all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
>   object for more information). The jqXHR.done() (for success),
>   jqXHR.fail() (for error), and jqXHR.always() (for completion, whether
>   success or error) methods take a function argument that is called when
>   the request terminates. For information about the arguments this
>   function receives, see the jqXHR Object section of the $.ajax()
>   documentation.
>
> The Promise interface in jQuery 1.5 also allows jQuery's Ajax methods,
>   including $.getJSON(), to chain multiple .done(), .always(), and
>   .fail() callbacks on a single request, and even to assign these
>   callbacks after the request may have completed. If the request is
>   already complete, the callback is fired immediately.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: yeah, I know that, but how comes firebug can access these properties while in javascript I can't? I just hate the inline function paradigm, and even in the example you give I still struggle to get the data in a variable in the outer scope (i'll need to clone it i suppose)

Comment: @nus: `how comes firebug can access these properties while in javascript I can't` What did you try? Remember that $.getJSON is asyn, so if you try to access the returned data immediately after that, the data may not arrive yet

Comment: sorry about that last comment. Obviously I can't just dump it in a variable in the outerscope because it is asynchronous. I'm just confused by the firebug output. Is firebug artificially putting together the jqXHR object?

Comment: @nus The properties are accessible to you just as they are to Firebug -- `test.responseText`. The difference between your code and Firebug is timing. Without using the callback, your code will expect it immediately. Firebug, on the other hand, waits a bit, giving the request time to finish.

Comment: so when i do `console.log( test );` firebug hooks into that ajax request with a callback function?

Comment: @nus: when you debug, debugging tools (like firebug) should report the `newest state` of your watched object and if your object properties change, the watch window will update to reflect that.

Comment: @nus Not for the Console (Net does, when enabled). But, `console.log()` is often asynchronous as well, waiting for a moment when the engine isn't busy to actually update the log. This wait can be enough time for the request to finish.